# Compare the X last frames of a live feed/ webcam and highlight their difference

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, detection, video-editing

As part of a project, I am trying to create a script that will

- detect motion using a camera, and when doing so,
- capture some frames of the feed for further analysis.

(But without delaying the actual feed!) Until now I am able to detect movement but without much say to the settings, so I am looking for a better solution.

What I cannot find a way to do is:
Hold on a frame while the feed plays.

What could help me a lot move forward:

- a way to store X previous frames. (It will be empty for the first X frames, and afterwards it will be replaced with the a frame rolling frame set.)
  or
- a way to store a frame X seconds before the current. (It will be empty for the first X seconds, and afterwards it will be replaced with the new frame.)

## What I have until now

```
import cv2, time, pandas        # importing OpenCV, time and Pandas library
import threading
from datetime import datetime       # importing datetime class from datetime library
```

My try to capture a previous frame, but it delays the feed:

```
def CheckFrame():
    threading.Timer(100.0 , CheckFrame).start()
    check, frame2 = video.read()    # second image
    return frame2
```

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)     # Capturing video


#check if connection with camera is successfully
if video.isOpened():
    ret, frame = video.read()  #capture a frame from live video

    #check whether frame is successfully captured
    if ret:
        # continue to display window until 'q'/Esc is pressed Check end of code
        while(True):


            check, frame = video.read()     #capture a frame from live video
           
            # frame Converting color image to gray_scale image
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)      
            # frame Converting gray scale image to GaussianBlur so that change can be find easily
            gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 10)      



            frame2 = CheckFrame()
            # frame2 Converting color image to gray_scale image
            gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)      
            # frame2 Converting gray scale image to GaussianBlur so that change can be find easily
            gray2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (21, 21), 10)      



            # Difference between rame2f and current frame
            diff_frame = cv2.absdiff(gray2, gray)     
        
            # If change in between static background and current frame is greater than 30 it will show white color(255)
            thresh_frame = cv2.threshold(diff_frame, 2, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 
            thresh_frame = cv2.dilate(thresh_frame, None, iterations = 1)
        
            # Finding contour of moving object
            cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)      

        
            for contour in cnts:
                if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1000:
                    continue
       
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                # making green rectangle around the moving object
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

            cv2.imshow("Color Frame", frame)      # Displaying color frame with contour of motion of object
            #cv2.imshow("Gray Frame", gray)      # Displaying image in gray_scale
            cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame", thresh_frame)   # Displaying the black and white image in which if intensity difference greater than 30 it will appear white
            cv2.imshow("Difference Frame", diff_frame)      # Displaying the difference in currentframe to the staticframe(very first_frame)


            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:     #press 'Esc' to break out of the loop
            #if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): #press 'q' to break out of the loop
                break

    #print error if frame capturing was unsuccessful
    else:
        print("Error : Failed to capture frame")

    video.release()
    
    # Destroying all the windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# print error if the connection with camera is unsuccessful

else:
    print("Cannot open camera")
```

Comment: What was your solution to this problem? I'm working on the same project, but for android.